# Jekyll custom plugin ignored in post.html page

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I created a Jekyll tag plugin, which works fine on all template (index/about/contact/default/page) except _layout/post.html. I have tried looking for a solution on Stackoverflow and Google, but I haven't found one yet.

I created a new "products" collection within which my custom Liquid-tag plugin called to render a block of HTML code on post.html. Here's the plugin,

```
module Jekyll
    class AmazonAffiateHelper < Liquid::Tag

        def initialize(tag_name, input, tokens)
            super
            @input = input
        end

        def render(context)
            input_split = split_params(@input)

            output = ""
            if (input_split.length > 0)
                href = input_split[0].strip
                src = input_split[1].strip
                src2 = input_split[2].strip
                href2 = input_split[3].strip

                output = "<a href=\"#{href}\" target=\"_blank\"><img border=\"0\" src=\"#{src}\""
                output += " width=\"150\" class=\"center-block amazon-fix \"></a>"
                output += " <img src=\"#{src2}\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\" border=\"0\""
                output += " alt=\"\" style=\"border:none !important; margin:0px !important;\"/>"
                output += " <br><br><a href=\"#{href2}\" class=\"btn btn-amazon amazon-fix\">"
                output += "BUY ON AMAZON</a>"
            end

            return output
        end

        def split_params(params)
            return params.split("|")
        end
    end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('amazon', Jekyll::AmazonAffiateHelper)
```

Resulting output for example is something like this,

```
Here's is a book you might like, {% amazon variable|variable2|variable3|variable4 %}
```

And I am not getting anything useful from `bundler exec jekyll server --trace`

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

PS: I am not a coder, but I am learning.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to work around it by creating a new jekyll-block plugin. Not sure why I need to do it this in the first place, but it works, and the solution is below - I am sure there must be a better way of doing it.

```
module Jekyll 
    class RecommendationBlock < Liquid::Block 
        def initialize(tag_name, markup, tokens) 
            super 
            @input = markup 
        end 
        
        def render(context) 
            contents = super 
            # very important for this solution
            content = Liquid::Template.parse(contents).render context 
            output = content 
            return output 
        end 
    end 
end 

Liquid::Template.register_tag("recommendation", Jekyll::RecommendationBlock)
```

And then, on the post.html, I loop through products collection

```
{% for product in site.products limit 5}
    # product.content has the custom amazon tag {% amazon variable1|variable2...%}, which is cause the problem
    {% recommendation recom }{{ product }}{% endrecommendation %}
{% endfor}
```

I hope it helps someone if they run into the same problem.

Thanks everyone.